# convert dataframe of symmetric pairs into pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe (df) of comparisons that are symmetric. a versus b = 2, so b versus a is 2 as well. Self comparisons are never listed but I'd like to list those as '0'.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5'])
df['Col1'] = ['a','a','a','b','b','c']
df['Col2'] = ['b','c','d','c','d','d']
df['Col3'] = [2,3,4,5,6,7]
df['Col4'] = ['ignore_me']*6
df['Col5'] = ['ignore_me']*6
```

I can get rid of columns I'm uninterested in, because they're named.

```
small_df = df.drop(['Col4', 'Col5'], axis=1)
>>> small_df
  Col1 Col2  Col3
0    a    b     2
1    a    c     3
2    a    d     4
3    b    c     5
4    b    d     6
5    c    d     7
```

Is there a function that converts these `small_df` pairs into a pivot table like one of these 3? lower-triangle, upper-triangle, or both doesn't matter

```
    a   b   c   d           a   b   c   d           a   b   c   d
a   0                   a   0   2   3   4       a   0   2   3   4
b   2   0               b       0   5   6       b   2   0   5   6
c   3   5   0           c           0   7       c   3   5   0   7
d   4   6   7   0       d               0       d   4   6   7   0
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different from your results (non-existent relations aren't filled), but what you are describing is a **`pivot_table`**

```
df.pivot_table(index='Col1', columns='Col2', values='Col3', fill_value=0)

Col2  b  c  d
Col1
a     2  3  4
b     0  5  6
c     0  0  7
```

Comment: I like this way. You can just reindex over both axes to get all of the self-relations.

Comment: thanks, this handles non-symmetric comparisons well, but to save time I just have one or the other- never both; a,b=2 present b,a=2 absent

Comment: The `df.combine_first(df.T)` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77242993/how-to-reshape-pandas-dataframe-into-a-symmetric-matrix-corr-like-square-matrix) is what I was most after. Thanks everyone!