# How to reshape pandas dataframe into a symmetric matrix (corr-like square matrix)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a df like below:

```
  name1 name2  value
0     A     B   1300
1     A     C    150
2     A     D    300
3     B     C    450
4     B     D    200
5     C     D    300
```

I tried to `pivot` the table to plot a corr-like heatmap based on the `value` column:

```
table = df.pivot(columns='name1', index='name2', values='value')
table
```

The result is:

```
name1       A      B      C
name2                      
B      1300.0    NaN    NaN
C       150.0  450.0    NaN
D       300.0  200.0  300.0
```

How can I create a square matrix that contains A-D in columns and rows with value of `name1` `name2` is same to `name2` `name1` (`A`/`B` = `B`/`A` = `1300`)?

Desired output:

```
        A       B      C      D
A     NaN  1300.0  150.0  300.0
B  1300.0     NaN  450.0  200.0
C   150.0   450.0    NaN  300.0
D   300.0   200.0  300.0    NaN
```

Reproducible input:

```
import pandas as pd

products_list = [['A', 'B', 1300],
                 ['A', 'C', 150],
                 ['A', 'D', 300],
                 ['B', 'C', 450],
                 ['B', 'D', 200],
                 ['C', 'D', 300]]

df = pd.DataFrame(products_list, columns=['name1', 'name2', 'value'])
```

Comment: `df.corr()` should do

Comment: @pavi2410 I don't want to calculate corr but trying to reshape the dataframe into corr-like table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) the [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) after pivoting:

```
# table = df.pivot(columns='name1', index='name2', values='value')
out = table.combine_first(table.T)
```

Output:

```
        A       B      C      D
A     NaN  1300.0  150.0  300.0
B  1300.0     NaN  450.0  200.0
C   150.0   450.0    NaN  300.0
D   300.0   200.0  300.0    NaN
```

Alternatively, but less elegant, swap the columns and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) before the `pivot`:

```
out = (pd.concat([df, df.rename(columns={'name1': 'name2', 'name2': 'name1'})])
         .pivot(columns='name1', index='name2', values='value')
       )
```

Comment: OMG! So great! Thanks.